# MS Identity not working when update to Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, identity

the following code of get a usermanager worked fine in my Core 2.x:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
      .Build();

    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    string connectionString = builder.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    services.AddIdentity<UserEntity, GroupEntity>(options =>
    {
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var context = provider.GetService<UserDbContext>();
    var userManager = provider.GetService<UserManager<UserEntity>>();
    var roleManager = provider.GetService<RoleManager<GroupEntity>>();
}
```

but when I update to Core 3.0, the following line throw exception:

```
var userManager = provider.GetService<UserManager<UserEntity>>();
```

with message

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[IdentityWebApiSample_Core30.Database.UserEntity]]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[IdentityWebApiSample_Core30.Database.UserEntity]'.
```

I updated packages, but also not work. So what should I do after update to Core 3.0?

Comment: You may just be missing `services.AddLogging();`

Answer (score 0):

Ilogger seems to be not automatically registered in Core 3.0

You need an ILogger service

```
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var logger = provider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(logger);
```

Comment: When `ILogger<Program>` can be resolved, the logger(factory) looks already registered?

Comment: Of sorry I wrote too quickly, you are right, thank you for the clarification. But the idea is to understand that UserManager needs an ILogger that is not in the services.

Comment: thanks for your help @Dmo, Henk fixed my problem in comment.

Comment: I can't resolve this error. Is anyone else having this problem? I've tried all the suggestions above, but nothing works.